# PowerShell Scope Identifier

Tags: powershell, scope

I'm a PowerShell newbie, trying to understand scopes better.  Is there a way to identify a scope from within the scope ? Some variable or function that would give me scope name or scope Guid or scope Id of some sort ?

How could I, for example, know if the local scope is the global scope ?

Comment: Please see my substantially rewritten answer, which now shows a more robust test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How could I, for example, know if the local scope is the global scope?

```
[bool] $isGlobalScope = -not $(try { Get-Variable -Scope 1 PSHOME } catch { })
```

`$PSHOME` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pshome) with option `AllScope`, so it is by definition present in each and very scope. It also has option `Constant`, which means that it cannot neither removed nor modified.

By asking [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) to retrieve this variable from the *parent* scope, `-Scope 1`, the operation *fails* if you're in the global scope, because the global scope is the root of the entire scope hierarchy and therefore has no parent.

The upshot is:

- If you're *not* in the global scope, the `Get-Variable` call *succeeds* and returns a *nonempty string* (PowerShell's home path).

  - The Boolean [`-not` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Logical_Operators) coerces that string to a *Boolean* (`[bool]`), which evaluates to `$false`, given that nonempty strings are considered `$true` (irrespective of their content) and negation is applied.
- If you *are* in the global scope, the attempt to access `-Scope 1` causes a *statement-terminating* error, which triggers the `catch` block of the [`try` / `catch` / `finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement.

  - Since the `catch` block takes no action, it behaves like `$null` in an expression context
  - `-not` coerces `$null` to a Boolean. `$null` is `$false` in a Boolean context, so the negation with `-not` evaluates to `$true`, indicating that the code runs in the global scope.

**Note**: Thread / background jobs and remote sessions have their *own* global scopes, and the test above cannot distinguish between them.

---

<sup>Note: The original form of this answer suggested `(Get-PSCallStack).Count -eq 1` as a test; [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack) outputs [`[System.Management.Automation.CallStackFrame]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.callstackframe) instances that describe the chain of invocations to the current scope in reverse order.
Therefore, however, this test doesn't detect running in the global scope via [dot-sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-).</sup>