# ScriptProperty can't access script's cmdlets when invoked as a command

Tags: powershell, powershell-core, powershell-5.1

Given code such as this MRE:

```
function Get-One {1}
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Demo' -MemberType 'ScriptProperty' -MemberName 'Test1' -Value {Get-Date}
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Demo' -MemberType 'ScriptProperty' -MemberName 'Test2' -Value {Get-One}
$example = [PSCustomObject]@{PSTypeName = 'Demo'}
$example
```

If I invoke it as `pwsh -File '.\Demo.ps1'` then all works as you'd expect / I get this output:

```
Test1               Test2
-----               -----
2021-04-17 21:35:55     1
```

However, if I invoke the same command as `pwsh -Command '.\Demo.ps1'` I get this (i.e. Test2 is blank); whilst I'd expect to get the same as the above:

```
Test1               Test2
-----               -----
2021-04-17 21:35:55
```

i.e. When I invoke via the `-Command` parameter, the ScriptProperty can't access cmdlets/functions defined within the script itself; though can access standard ones (e.g. `Get-Date`).

I'd assume this was a bug; only the same behaviour's seem in both PWSH and PowerShell; which makes that a little less likely.

Is this a bug; or am I missing something in my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference in behavior is explained by the fact that **`-File` implicitly [*dot-sources*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the target script file, which means that it runs in the *global* scope**.

Typically, this detail is of little consequence (except if you also pass `-NoExit` to request staying in the session after the script terminates).

Here, it makes the crucial difference:

- **With `-File`, `Get-One` ends up defined in the *global* scope, which is the prerequisite for the `ScriptProperty`-defining `{ Get-One }` script block being able to see it**.
- By contrast, running the script file with `-Command` does *not* dot-source it, making the `Get-One` command effectively invisible to the `{ Get-One }` script block - and errors occurring inside such `ScriptProperty`-defining script blocks are quietly *ignored*.

There are two **solutions**:

- Either: Explicitly define your `Get-One` function as *global*:

  ```
  function global:Get-One { 1 }
  ```
- Or: When using `-Command`, *explicitly dot-source* the script:

  ```
   pwsh -Command '. .\Demo.ps1'
  ```

Comment: That's fantastic; thank-you.  I've knocked up a cmdlet to test for the global context to run at the start of my script to ensure it's run correctly (possibly the GUID's overkill; just added in case the same global variable was assigned a value elsewhere). 
 
`function Test-GlobalContext {
    [Guid]$expected = [Guid]::NewGuid();
    Set-Variable -Scope 1 -Name 'InGlobalContextTest' -Value $expected;
    [bool]($global:InGlobalContextTest -eq $expected);
    Remove-Variable -Scope 1 -Name 'InGlobalContextTest' ;
}`

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, helped, @JohnLBevan. A simpler way may be `[bool] $isGlobalScope = -not $(try { Get-Variable -Scope 1 PSHOME } catch { })` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59081086/45375).